# WebSocket opening handshake timed out in https

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, websocket, uwsgi

WebSocket connection to 'wss://ip_address:8008/ws/events?subscribe-broadcast' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

**its timed out only when open UI in HTTPS, in HTTP its working...**

I have generated the certificate using OpenSSL in ubuntu

my uwsgi configuration is

```
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock   
chmod-socket = 666  
socket-timeout = 60 
chdir = <django path>
wsgi-file  = <django_path>/wsgi.py
virtualenv = <path_to_virtualenv>
vacuum = true
enable-threads  = true
threads=500
startup-timeout = 15
graceful-timeout = 15
http-socket=<my_ip>:8008
http-websockets=true
```

my nginx configuration is

```
server {
listen <ip>:80 default;
listen <ip>:443 ssl http2 default_server;
ssl_certificate <path>/generate_crt.crt;
ssl_certificate_key <path>/generated_key.key;
client_body_buffer_size 500M;
client_body_timeout 300s;
keepalive_timeout 5000;
client_max_body_size 700M;
access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log;
root /tmp/MVM_APPS/angularjs/dist;
index index.html index.htm;
server_name localhost;
location /api {
uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 120;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 1000;
}
location /ws/ {
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
proxy_pass http://<ip>:8008;
proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}
location /static {
    alias /<path>/static;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
}
```

I am using Django with WS4redis package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For web-sockets to work over Tls(wss) protocol you would need to generate ssl certificates, after generating the certificates add the following line to uwsgi.ini file.

```
https-socket=[ip]:[port], /path_to_server_certificate, /path_to_key
```

and restart the server (optionally you can also pass 2 more fields [,ciphers,ca])
more details can be found [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Changelog-1.9.20.html).

Alternatively, if your message broker is capable, you can directly expose it to client using some messaging protocol like Mqtt or Stomp

Comment: Wow, will try it and let you know the update... ;-)